# What statistical tool should I use to determine the best and worst dependent variable from two measured independent variable?

Tags: inference

I am researching the effect of temperature on the water-resistant properties of paper by measuring contact angle and water absorption. How can I determine the best and worst temperatures using the values from the two parameters? Thank you.